# Solved Problems in Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, algebraic-number-theory

I'm not too sure whether this is the right place to ask this (and *please* correct me if it is not), but I'm currently studying a course in Algebraic Number Theory and would like to be pointed in the direction of any **solved** problems that can assist in learning.

I have the book *Problems in Algebraic Number Theory* by Murty and Esmonde, which is particularly good, but are there any further sources (inc. online) available that do a similar job?

It is so often frustrating to be presented with an extensive list of practice questions, many of which form part of the exposition of the material (as in *Number Fields* by Marcus for example) and then to have no real way of knowing whether any solution you generate is correct and has not made any oversights.

MSE is undoubtedly a good place to verify any answers and clear up issues, but question limits and the impracticality of going online every time a solution seems suspect (or the question is computational and lacks any result to check against) form a barrier.

I suppose any ANT textbook that has an accompanying solutions manual or online published solutions is what I have in mind. Or failing that, links to institutions running a course in ANT with answers to homework exercises.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Robert Ash's book on algebraic number theory, which can be found here:

http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/ANT.html

contains solutions to all the exercises.

Answer (score 11):

The lecture notes of J. S. Milne on algebraic number theory has exercises with solutions, see
http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ant.html,

appendix A: Solutions to the exercises.

Comment: Many thanks. Both your answer and that of @Pete Klimek have been very useful. The decision is to which I should accept was arbitrary.